# rails 3 link_to :remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I am somewhat new to RoR, and I am trying to use link_to to reload a portion of the page with div id "current_submission", with

```
-for submission in @submissions
    =link_to submission.title, "/submissions/#{submission.id}/display_attachment", :remote=>true
%div#current_submission
```

I want the content of "/submissions/#{submission.id}/display_attachment" to be displayed in the bottom of the page when the title of the submission is clicked. I don't know javascript yet, and the examples I have seen seem to require writing a function in javascript? I thought the point of AJAX was to avoid the need to breach the Rails abstraction by learning javascript. Do I need to learn javascript to implement this? Also, I am using jquery instead of prototype.

I watched RailsCast #205, but am still pretty confused.

Comment: The point of AJAX is to update content on the page with server data without reloading the page.  You have to know a little bit of javascript, but with jQuery, it's not hard.  Check out <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305378/ruby-on-rails-jquery-to-get-data-using-ajax>.

Comment: AJAX is an acronym for *Asynchronous **JavaScript** and XML*, and jQuery is a JavaScript library. The point of AJAX is to asynchronously communicate (read/write content) with the server resources and your rendered application in the client. So if you want to load some content that belongs to that resource without re-loading the page, you'll need to use AJAX. It's gonna use the id of that submission, go to the server, grab content, bring back to you, and you'll have to use JavaScript to manipulate the content, for example load the content in the DOM element which is on the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you. My goal is to add asynchronous responses to my application. I have gained confidence with Rails, but I feel somewhat overwhelmed with tangental things I don't know: javascript,jquery, xml, AJAX. I tried to learn AJAX from the top-down on the rails guide website, but that  has been unenlightening. 

Would you recommend that I instead learn JavaScript from the bottom-up, and that I write my methods in JavaScript rather than using AJAX? 
Simply put: what should my next move be?

Comment: In this day and age, JavaScript has become **very** important to web development, so leave your fears behind and learn it. Not only JavaScript, but whatever else you need in order to write web apps. As for your next move, learn JS, and learn it well, otherwise you're gonna spin (a lot) when using libraries like jQuery since it's built *with* JS, so you have to know the core concepts: how does JS work? how does AJAX work? how do I do "x"? how do I extend "x" function? how do I debug this error in my console? ... think like this: *You have to know the alphabet before you know how to write*